# Transit through UK with Irish visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian citizen, with Irish short stay visa (under BIVS). I am going from Delhi to LHR, and then Stansted to Dublin.  So I need to change  airport. In that case do I need a UK transit visa? I got this from the UK embassy website, but I am a little confused. Can anyone please confirm this?

> **What if I’m flying to Ireland first, but my flight transits through a UK airport?**
>
> *That is fine, and you can do that with a BIVS visa issued by Ireland. You will need to complete the transit and travel to an official port of entry in Ireland within 24 hours of arriving at the UK airport.*

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to think the UK government source you have found is lying -- and why would you believe random people on the internet rather than the embassy?

Comment: And if an embassy website is not good enough for you, then how about gov.uk? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme says: "Holders of an Irish short stay visa will be able to transit in the UK as part of an onward journey to Ireland."

Comment: I am in exact same situation, so would like to know if you were able to transit through London without any issue with the BIVS stamped Ireland short term visa? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a transit visa for UK.

> **6. Transit**
>
> Individuals with an eligible visa under the British-Irish visa scheme will not need to apply for a UK transit visa if their flight takes them via the UK to Ireland. Passengers will need to travel in to Ireland by 23:59 on the day after arrival.

Source: **[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme)**